# New to E4 (Styling UI with css). Confused with TabFolder & CTabFolder

Tags: css, eclipse

I am learning the E4. Trying to add styling css to my simple RCP. I've use the `TabFolder` & `TabItem` in my code, but when I tried:

```
CTabFolder, CTabItem {
  background-color: red;
}
```

It does not affect the UI, then I tried

```
TabFolder, TabItem {
background-color: red;}
```

This does not work, either.

I did a quick search in internet and found that all the samples are using `CTabFolder, CTabItem`. And nobody tells the `TabFolder, TabItem`

I got confused on it. What's the difference between them? And what kind of css could work properly for components `TabFolder, TabItem`?

Comment: Are you running an E4 application, or trying to add CSS to an RCP application?

Comment: Yes, I've add a simple css to my RCP application. And it works. I've found that the bgColor of CTabFolder & CTabItem changed. But TabFolder, TabItem not work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the CSS Spy and CSS Scratchpad, to see the available properties, and test the possible combinations.

For a list of SWT - CSS mappings for CTabFolder, you can visit this page: https://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/CSS/SWT_Mapping#Widget:_CTabFolder

Below, you can see a CSS with a simple example

```
CTabFolder Composite {
  background-color: pink;
}

CTabFolder CTabItem {
  background-color: lime;
  color: green;
}

CTabFolder CTabItem:selected {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

And then see the result in the image below, applied using the CSS Scratchpad

[image: Example using CSS Scratchpag]